# Starting an asp.net project from a file except Default .aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, project

I wanna start my project from a file except `Default.aspx` 
e.g : `MasterFile.aspx`

Is there a setting for doing that in `Visual Studio 2010`?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't Right click on file and `Set as Start Page` help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default page settings is somewhat different from one version of `IIS` to another version.

If you have IIS7 or IIS Express then add following entry in web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="MasterFile.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Or you may use urlMappings,

```
<system.web>
     ....
    <urlMappings>
      <add url="~/Default.aspx" mappedUrl="~/MasterFile.aspx"/>
    </urlMappings>
</system.web>
```

[Setting Up Default Documents (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 1):

Plus to the comment above, when you deploy on IIS set the default document name to MasterFile.aspx in the virtual directory or application configuration and page will be loaded also when users only have application url  in browsers.